# GitCI ssh to server returns bash: go: command not found

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have Go installed on my server. When I login through CLI I can successfully execute the "go build" and other commands.

Except when I SSH from my GitlabCI. I get this error:

> bash: go: command not found

The code I am using currently:

```
ssh root@111.111.111.111"export PATH=$PATH:/root/.go/bin/go && cd /var/www/mysite.com/api && go build && exit"
```

As said, when I do it manually on my server it works perfectly, it just wont work when I do it through GitlabCI and I cannont figure out why.

I installed Go on my (Ubunto 18.04) server by using the guide here: https://golang.org/doc/install

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: How did you installed go on your server ?

Comment: Good question, its been a long time, but I recon I followed these steps: https://golang.org/doc/install i.e. download tar, untar, install and set the Go path.

Comment: Did you add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` in /etc/profile ?
Do you know where your script expect to find the Go binary ?

Comment: Honestly no clue what /etc/profile is. All I did was execute the command as given in the golang.org documentatie which was: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin. The weird thing is, that when I use "whereis Go" it says: /root/.go/bin/go. I am still learning to find my way around servers. When I "ls -la" on /usr/local/ I see there is no go folder. Thats why I used "/root/.go/bin/go" in my GitlabCI command.

Comment: Did you tried to use `/root/.go/bin/go` instead of `go` in your script/command ? You can also try to create a symlink like that: `ln -s /root/.go/bin/go /usr/local/go/bin/go`

Comment: Good suggestion, I will try those options and let you know the outcome. Thanks so much for your replies! will let you know the outcome.

Comment: It is working perfectly when I use the symlink (or /root/.go/bin/go). Thank you so much for your help NRE!

Answer (score 0):

As [NRE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8657570/nre) said, either a Symlink or "/root/.go/bin/go" would do the job and it sure did. Finally got it working now!